# Discord.py Cogs cooldowns?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a problem, when I try to build a cooldown "handler" into a discord.py cog, it sends the message etc., but the cooldown message is still sent and the cooldown doesn't work either.

I've tried everything, but I really can't get any further...

Hope someone has a solution!

Thanks in advance

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import json
import random
import typing

from colorama import Fore, init
from datetime import timedelta

from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, Select, SelectOption

init()

with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
    prefix = config["prefix"]
    token = config["token"]

class Fish(commands.Cog):

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
            await ctx.message.delete()
            sec = round(error.retry_after)
            td = str(timedelta(seconds=sec))
            x = td.split(':')
            em = discord.Embed(title=f"Yo, chill and wait {x[0]}h, {x[1]}m, {x[2]}s!", color=0xf1c40f)
            em.set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
            await ctx.send(embed=em, delete_after=30)

    @commands.cooldown(1, 60, commands.BucketType.user)
    @commands.guild_only()
    @commands.command(aliases=["f"], description='Fish some fishes', help="f")
    async def fish(self, ctx):
        #code

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Fish(client))```
````

Comment: Cooldown is an exception. You need an error handler to get the cooldown.

Comment: You're missing which listener you want to listen, try `@commands.Cog.listener("on_command_error")`.

Comment: Nope, same error

Comment: What's the error? Also, have you tried putting `@commands.command` at the top, and then the other decorators below it?

Comment: There is no error message, it sent's the cooldown message after the command was used

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer!
In the on_message method there was the

```
await self.client.process_commands(message)
```

because of this, the bot sent 2 messages every time!